User Sign up using Invitation flow | Send email to user using MicrosoftOnlineService ONLY
While using using Sign up invitation flow in Azure B2C using custom policy, I want to send  invitation email to user using Microsoft native email provider. I want to use the Microsoft native email provider which is generally used by MS while sending verification code or OTP for example during Forgot password flow journey.
I am aware of the solution of using 3rd party mail provider like SendGrid , Mailjet or SendInBlue. Hence please ignore them.
I have tried the 3rd party email provider like SendGrid and that works well. But i am not seeing any documentation with regards to sending email using msonlineservices.

The element "PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" sends an email using the Microsoft infrastructure.
If msonlineservices has some sort of mail API, you could use that?

Hi , verified.email is always on the context of user who sign in , hence the email address will user email address only. Please share api if any for msonlineservices as i was not able to trace the same from any documentation.
